# Change value in layout.xml conditionally in Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to get android:layout_marginEnd="-6dp" to change to 2dp conditionally in:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/wifi_combo"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginEnd="-6dp"
    >
```

My condition is:

```
if (mSignalClusterStyle == STYLE_ALWAYS) {
            mMobileType.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (mWifiVisible) {
            mMobileType.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

I would like to add a line to the if statement that overrides the -6dp with 2dp in the xml file.

I have explored setMarginEnd(), but there are very few resources on this, seeing as it is only a year old, and I keep getting a compile error with it.

What is the best way to change android:layout_marginEnd on a condition programmatically?

Comment: what is the compile error you get while you try [setMarginEnd()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMarginEnd(int))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.wifi_combo);      
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMarginEnd(2);
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! I had to change 'FrameLayout.LayoutParams' to 'LayoutParams params', but it worked. I was forgetting the 'layout.getLayoutParams();'

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set the endMargin is using setMarginEnd() only, added in API 17.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMarginEnd(int)

BTW, what compile errors you are getting?